# Create function that require other repeatbale logic as pre-requiste (clean code)

Tags: go, dependency-injection, interface

I've the following yaml file which I need to `parse` (the parse is working as expected) and need to provide a `data`from the yaml file content that should be exposed by the following **decoupled functions**

I need to provide the following functions (here is example of some of those functions, need more with the same pattern...)

> getApps()
>
> getServices()
>
> GetApp(appname)
>
> GetServiceForApp(appname)

This is the code (which works...)

```
var DMZ = []byte(`
applications:
  - name: app1
    type: php
    src: /app1
    host: us
    use: 
      - redis
      - mysql

  - name: app2
    type: rust
    src: /app2
    host: eu
    use: 
      - mongo
      - mysql

  - name: app3
    type: golang
    src: /app3
    host: us
    use: 
      - postgress
      - mysql


services:
  - name: mongo
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: mysql
    type: db
    host: eu

  - name: postgress
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: redis
    type: db
    host: us   
`)
```

**This is the structs**

```
type DMZ struct {
  Applications       []*Applications   `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
  Services           []*Services       `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

type Applications struct {
  Name        string
  Type        string
  Src        string            `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
  use        []Use             `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Services struct {
  Name        string
  Type        string
  Host        string            `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}
type Use struct {
  Name       string     `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
  host       string     `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
  Type       string     `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
}



// Parse file
func Parse(yamlContent []byte) (out DMZ, err error) {
  dmz := DMZ{}
  err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz)
  if err != nil {
    logs.Error("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
  }
  return dmz, err
}
```

As the `Parse` function is a **per-requite** **to all the needed functions** (which I listed above)  I wonder how is the **best** to create them ,create simple function that **every time** call to the `parse` function and then do the logic (not a problem)  but I wonder if there is **better approach** which follows the **clean code principles** for Golang , with '**interface / dependency injections'** ?

**UPDATE:**

I want to **avoid** doing things like following, assume that I need to call to those function from **different packages** or **even different GitHub repository**  how it's best to do it with Golang **clean code.**

```
func getApps(){

 dmz := Parse()
....
}


func getServices(){

 dmz := Parse()
....

}


func getApp(appname string){

 dmz := Parse()
....

}


func GetServiceForApp(appname string){

 dmz := Parse()
....

}
```

And I need more functions with the same pattern ...

What I need some **Clean Code** solution using **interface/dependency injection** like a best practice code example in Golang

If something is not clear please let me know :)

Comment: I don't get your question quite properly, but one uses `func init(){}` to initialize things, it also includes reading config files...

Comment: @nilsocket - No I dont want to use the init function, I want to use more interface/dependency injection , can you please provide example how would you solve my problem ?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to inject this data into? You're showing config file parsing, but not where you actually need to use the configuration.

Comment: I don't known, and I don't think it's easy to implement it either, you can look at new [library](https://github.com/google/go-cloud/tree/master/wire) for go-cloud dependency injection.

Comment: You can also look at a dependency injection engine like https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo which would do the DI for you, which really sounds like what you want.  It is kind of difficult to say exactly though

Comment: @Will-  Please see my update , is it more clearer now . In addition I've put a bounty :) thanks

Comment: @shopiaT do you need parse function to be called only once through out all functions, or you want to parse it each and everyTime the function is called or parse it once for each new type of function call?

Comment: @shopiaT It is unclear from the question that what you want to achieve. Why you want to implement DI. Do you want a single parse function to return the exact parsed data likes services or apps.

Comment: @Himanshu - think that the parse can be called multi times , or just once . it depends on scenario . lets assume that it should be read multiple times...

Comment: @shopiaT you can use parse once if it is parsing a single yaml and then use pointer to struct and return particular object from different functions

Comment: @Himanshu - can this achieved with interface and DI ? if yes it will be great if you could provide example

Comment: @shopiaT go works different from other OOP language in which you are not creating an object/struct instance inside the constructor and then passing the value inside other classes to inject the dependency. But you can implement the interface on the struct by implementing all the functions defined inside the interface. Still I do not thing there is any requirement until you are implementing the functions in multiple package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the value inside pointer type struct value which will store the value inside the struct pointed by a pointer. Then Create method receives on All the methods from which you want to get the value of an app or service inside the struct.

Using pointer receiver in all methods you will be able to access the original struct which is updated when parsing the yaml.

Create a pointer to empty instance of the struct and pass it as a method receiver. Then access that struct in unmarshal to update yaml data in original struct. Access the updated struct in every function by accessing the value of original struct using pointer receiver to method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var dmz = []byte(`
applications:
  - name: app1
    type: php
    src: /app1
    host: us
    use: 
      - redis
      - mysql

  - name: app2
    type: rust
    src: /app2
    host: eu
    use: 
      - mongo
      - mysql

  - name: app3
    type: golang
    src: /app3
    host: us
    use: 
      - postgress
      - mysql


services:
  - name: mongo
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: mysql
    type: db
    host: eu

  - name: postgress
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: redis
    type: db
    host: us   
`)

type DMZ struct {
    Applications []*Applications `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
    Services     []*Services     `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

type Applications struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Src  string `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
    use  []Use  `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Services struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}
type Use struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
    host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
    Type string `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    dm := &DMZ{}
    result, err := dm.Parse(dmz)
    dm.getApp("app1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println(dm.getApp("app2"))
    fmt.Println(dm.GetServiceForApp("mongo"))
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getApps() []*Applications {
    return dmz.Applications
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getServices() []*Services {
    return dmz.Services
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getApp(appname string) *Applications {
    for _, value := range dmz.Applications {
        if appname == value.Name {
            fmt.Println((*value).Name)
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (dmz *DMZ) GetServiceForApp(appname string) *Services {
    for _, value := range dmz.Services {
        if appname == value.Name {
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Parse file
func (dmz *DMZ) Parse(yamlContent []byte) (out *DMZ, err error) {
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    }
    return dmz, err
}
```

Working code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5WyjTNtjj27)

If you want your code to be more clean then you can also skip the struct returned from parse function. Since we are passing a pointer type receiver and updating the original struct as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var dmz = []byte(`
applications:
  - name: app1
    type: php
    src: /app1
    host: us
    use: 
      - redis
      - mysql

  - name: app2
    type: rust
    src: /app2
    host: eu
    use: 
      - mongo
      - mysql

  - name: app3
    type: golang
    src: /app3
    host: us
    use: 
      - postgress
      - mysql


services:
  - name: mongo
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: mysql
    type: db
    host: eu

  - name: postgress
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: redis
    type: db
    host: us   
`)

type DMZ struct {
    Applications []*Applications `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
    Services     []*Services     `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

type Applications struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Src  string `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
    use  []Use  `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Services struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}
type Use struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
    host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
    Type string `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    dm := &DMZ{}
    dm.Parse(dmz)
    fmt.Println(dm.getApp("app2"))
    fmt.Println(dm.GetServiceForApp("mongo"))
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getApps() []*Applications {
    return dmz.Applications
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getServices() []*Services {
    return dmz.Services
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getApp(appname string) *Applications {
    for _, value := range dmz.Applications {
        if appname == value.Name {
            fmt.Println((*value).Name)
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (dmz *DMZ) GetServiceForApp(appname string) *Services {
    for _, value := range dmz.Services {
        if appname == value.Name {
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Parse file
func (dmz *DMZ) Parse(yamlContent []byte) {
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

As we can notice that Parse function will become more clean since we are not returning anything from it we are just updating the original struct using method receiver which is a much better way to achieve what you have been trying  to achieve.

You can also choose to implement an interface by defining the methods in struct as receiver for which you are trying to implement the interface as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type DI interface {
    GetApps() []*Applications
    GetServices() *Services
}

var dmz = []byte(`
applications:
  - name: app1
    type: php
    src: /app1
    host: us
    use: 
      - redis
      - mysql

  - name: app2
    type: rust
    src: /app2
    host: eu
    use: 
      - mongo
      - mysql

  - name: app3
    type: golang
    src: /app3
    host: us
    use: 
      - postgress
      - mysql


services:
  - name: mongo
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: mysql
    type: db
    host: eu

  - name: postgress
    type: db
    host: us

  - name: redis
    type: db
    host: us   
`)

type DMZ struct {
    Applications []*Applications `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
    Services     []*Services     `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

type Applications struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Src  string `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
    use  []Use  `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Services struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}
type Use struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
    host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
    Type string `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    dm := &DMZ{}
    dm.Parse(dmz)
    fmt.Println(dm.getApp("app2"))
    fmt.Println(dm.GetServiceForApp("mongo"))
}

func (dmz *DMZ) GetApps() []*Applications {
    return dmz.Applications
}

func (dmz *DMZ) GetServices() []*Services {
    return dmz.Services
}

func (dmz *DMZ) getApp(appname string) *Applications {
    for _, value := range dmz.Applications {
        if appname == value.Name {
            fmt.Println((*value).Name)
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (dmz *DMZ) GetServiceForApp(appname string) *Services {
    for _, value := range dmz.Services {
        if appname == value.Name {
            return value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Parse file
func (dmz *DMZ) Parse(yamlContent []byte) {
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

**Note:**

> Generics are convenient but they come at a cost in complexity in the
>   type system and run-time. We haven't yet found a design that gives
>   value proportionate to the complexity, although we continue to think
>   about it. Meanwhile, Go's built-in maps and slices, plus the ability
>   to use the empty interface to construct containers (with explicit
>   unboxing) mean in many cases it is possible to write code that does
>   what generics would enable, if less smoothly.

Comment: HI, 1. Do you think that interface is not a good case here ?  2. should the parse function needs to be in the `init` method since its a pre requiste to all the functions?

Comment: @shopiaT If you want to have a good implementation. You should not go with init. Because init works before main starts execution and init() basically used when you are interacting with your system like initializing a database connection or configuring your system prerequisites. But since the data you are getting is from web api. So you are going to interact with an api. Then there are other things too like HTTP response, verbs and status codes which probably you need to handle before you unmarshal the data whch cannot be managed inside init.

Comment: Hi, Regard the interface, you didn't give me an answer :). anyhow, it will be great if you can adapt to the `last example of you` to an solution which include of using `interface` . have a nice weekend

Comment: @shopiaT Interfaces are implemented if you want to create a bridge between two structs which is not your case you can create an interface and then implement all the methods on the struct to fulfill the interface but think about it what is the use of it what is that you want to achieve.

Comment: I try to use your code and add interface without success, any idea what could be missing ? `type DI interface {
 GetApps() []*Applications
 GetServices() *Services
}`

Comment: @shopiaT try this link to implement the interface https://play.golang.org/p/gFOcrgggUmZ. One more thing if you want to pass other functions also implement the same with passing the struct as a receiver on which you are implementing the `DI` interface

Comment: @shopiaT one thing always worth noticing is that golang does not works like other OOP languages. So better is not to treat it like such and think from a different perspective . I am also coming from OOP language background. So initially I have also faced some issues.

Comment: @shopiaT go has his own efficient design patterns better is to use those. There are better approaches to achieve something efficient inside go.

Comment: @shopiaT thanks. I will be happy to in future help also. just message me whenever you have some issue regarding golang.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface and provide implementations in the struct

```
type DMZI interface {
    GetApps() []Application
    GetService() []Service
    GetApp(name string) (Application, error)
    GetServiceForApp(name string) ([]string, error)
}

type DMZ struct {
    Application []Application `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
    Service     []Service     `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

func (dmz DMZ) GetApps() []Application {
    return dmz.Application
}

func (dmz DMZ) GetService() []Service {
    return dmz.Service
}

func (dmz DMZ) GetApp(name string) (Application, error) {
    for _, app := range dmz.Application {
        if app.Name == name {
            return app, nil
        }
    }
    return Application{}, fmt.Errorf("Did not find application with name %s", name)
}

func (dmz DMZ) GetServiceForApp(name string) ([]string, error) {
    app, err := dmz.GetApp(name)
    if err != nil {
        return []string{}, err
    }
    return app.Use, nil
}

type Application struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Src  string   `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
    Use  []string `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Service struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}

// Parse file
func Parse(yamlContent []byte) (out DMZI, err error) {
    dmz := DMZ{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    }
    return dmz, err
}
```

So, you can call the methods on the returned interface e.g.

```
fmt.Printf("Apps : %+v\n", dmz.GetApps())
fmt.Printf("Service : %+v\n", dmz.GetService())
```

**UPDATE**

main method as requested in the comment

```
func main() {
    dmz, err := Parse([]byte(ymlStr))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Apps : %+v\n", dmz.GetApps())
    fmt.Printf("Service : %+v\n", dmz.GetService())
}
```

Will print

```
Apps : [{Name:app1 Type:php Src:/app1 Use:[redis mysql]} {Name:app2 Type:rust Src:/app2 Use:[mongo mysql]} {Name:app3 Type:golang Src:/app3 Use:[postgress mysql]}]
Service : [{Name:mongo Type:db Host:us} {Name:mysql Type:db Host:eu} {Name:postgress Type:db Host:us} {Name:redis Type:db Host:us}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole code ? with the main section since I dont understad how the flow will work without filling the `dmz` object, example for all the follow will help to understand your proposed solution...

Comment: Thanks, will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a little and done what I *think* you are asking for, which is to always call "Parse" whenever you create a new instance of DMZ.  This is how you would do this using [Dargo](https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo).  Look at the bottom to see how the code would bind DMZ into a ServiceLocator and how to get new instances of DMZ

```
type DMZ struct {
    Applications []*Applications `yaml:"applications,omitempty"`
    Services     []*Services     `yaml:"services,omitempty"`
}

// This method is called every time DMZ is created via the Dargo API
func (dmz *DMZ) DargoInitialize(ioc.Descriptor) error {
    // get ur bytes from... wherever
    Parse(dmz, []byte{})
}

type Applications struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Src  string `yaml:"src,omitempty"`
    use  []Use  `yaml:"use,omitempty"`
}
type Services struct {
    Name string
    Type string
    Host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
}
type Use struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
    host string `yaml:"host,omitempty"`
    Type string `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
}

// Parse file
func Parse(dmz *DMZ, yamlContent []byte) (out *DMZ, err error) {
    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlContent), &dmz)
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    }
    return dmz, err
}

func useDargo() error {
    locator, err := ioc.CreateAndBind("example", func(binder ioc.Binder) error {
        binder.Bind("DMZ", &DMZ{}).InScope(ioc.PerLookup)
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // This is how you would get your instances of DMZ
    locator.GetDService("DMZ")
}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) sorry but I cannot use any open source (my company current restriction :-( ) , it will be great if you can add some example without open source , I think that Golang is supporting it Out of the box with interface ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure go doesn't support anything like the above out of the box, though I could be wrong